# Call a function dynamically from a variable - Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Ok so I have two files, `filename1.py` and `filename2.py` and they both have a function with same name `funB`. The third file `process.py` has function that calls function from either files. I seem to be struggling in calling the correct function.

In `process.py`:

```
from directoryA.filename1 import funB
from directoryA.filename2 import funB

def funA:

    #do stuff to determine which filename and save it in variable named 'd'
    d = 'filename2'
    # here i want to call funB with *args based on what 'd' is
```

So i have tried `eval()` like so:

```
 call_right_funB = eval(d.funB(*args))
```

but it seems not to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just `from directoryA.filename1 import funB as f1` in this case? Or do you really need to dynamically lookup the module?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks,  Yes I need to dynamically look up the module

Comment: They're not "directory.filename" but "package.module" or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala its 'package.module' I used 'directory.filename' for simplifying and clarification purpose only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you can't use `eval()` with a combination of a string and a method like that. What you have written is:

```
call_right_funB = eval('filename'.funB(*args))
```

What you can do is:

```
call_right_funB = eval(d + '.funB(*args)')
```

But this is not very pythonic approach.
I would recommend creating a dictionary switch. Even though you have to import entire module:

```
import directoryA.filename1
import directoryA.filename2

dic_switch = {1: directoryA.filename1, 2: directoryA.filename2}
switch_variable = 1
call_right_funB = dic_switch[switch_variable].funB(*args)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, the first "unpythonic" way works fine. With Dictionary switch how would i call then function 'funB'

Comment: You are welcome :-)  
`call_right_funB = dict_switch[switch_variable].funB(*args)` should work fine.  
Edit:  
If you are using it only once, you can also do:  
`call_right_funB = {1: filename1, 2: filename2}[switch_variable].funB(*args)`

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'funB'

Comment: @darth haven't you write dictionary values as strings? Notice that in `dict_switch` they are saved as keywords, not as strings.

Comment: It was string but if i save as keywords I get TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Well, thats strange. I tried it with 'math' module like this: `{1: math}[1].sqrt(2)` and it worked perfectly. There must be something I am missing. I'll try it properly in one of my projects, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154587/discussion-between-bluepat-and-darth).